# Open existing Android Studio project in Windows Bash

Tags: android, bash, android-studio, windows-terminal

I want to open an existing Android Studio project from Windows Terminal, bash is the shell.

[image: .bashrc command]

I have tried `paxas project_directory`, and nothing happened. `convertPathFormat()` works properly, but not sure what's wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: it should be possible with `"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe" "C:\path\to\your_project"`. Dont have a windows machine atm to test it

Comment: @kampias isnt this a windows path? im on bash, not powershell or cmd